# AWS Connect : How do I show company name on outbound calls instead of a phone number , or maybe both?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, caller-id

I have been trying to show up the company name instead of a phone number when an outbound call is initiated automatically at certain times using aws connect contact flow. So far, everything is working as it should be except for showing up the name of the company. I have been trying to find a solution or a documentation on how to show the company name instead of a number but so far could not find anything useful. the only hint I got from aws documentation was , I should set the caller id and name by myself, and no further instruction or hints on how to do it. I Tried to change the phone number using outboundcall api's contact attributes but nothing was showing up.

```
$result = $client->startOutboundVoiceContact([
                'Attributes' => array(
                                    'sourcePhoneNumber' => $d->company_name,
                                    'd`enter code here`ate'=> $d->date,
                                    'time' => $d->time,
                                    'clinic' => $d->company_branch_name,
                                    'address' => $d->company_branch_address,

                                ),

            'ContactFlowId' => $this->contactFlowId, // REQUIRED
            'DestinationPhoneNumber' => $d->phone_number, // REQUIRED
            'InstanceId' => $this->instanceId, // REQUIRED
            'SourcePhoneNumber' => $this->sourcePhoneNumber,
        ]);
```

'''
where $d is my database and i am getting all the information from there

any recommendation or solution would be very much helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly this feature is only possible in the US.